# How can you tell when user clicked cancel from a JavaScript prompt() with a default?

Tags: javascript, default, prompt

Normally, if you ask a user a question with `prompt` like the following and the user hits cancel, then the `prompt` function returns `null`:

```
var name = prompt('What is your name?');
var hitCancel = name === null;
```

Works great, except now I want to put a default answer in the prompt:

```
var name = prompt('What is your name?', 'Fred');
```

Now even if the user hits cancel, 'Fred' will be returned! Even if the user types in 'Smith' and they click cancel, 'Fred' will still be returned! How can I tell when the user clicked cancel?

***UPDATE***: Forgot to mention that I had tested this in Firefox and Chrome. I know there are other libraries for user input, but in my particular case I need to use the `prompt` function.

***UPDATE 2***: "\x00Fred" was suggested to use as the default. Noticed something interesting there. If you click cancel, then "Fred" is what's returned. However, if you just click ok, then "\x00Fred" is returned. I wish it was the other way around! Because I don't know if someone wrote in "Fred" or they clicked cancel.

***UPDATE 3***: I feel very silly, the issue was with my code. `prompt` was in fact returning `null` when hitting cancel!

Comment: Store the original value (to compare later) and don't pre-populate the prompt with an acceptable value.

Comment: You can try prompt `"\x00Fred"` and check if they changed the string

Comment: @megawac Of course if they happen to be called "Fred" and click OK you'll discard the answer.

Comment: You could also just use one of the many DHTML dialog libraries that aren't constrained by the limitations of ancient DOM functions.

Comment: In what browser are you testing? I do the test and when I click cancel null is returned

Comment: `alert` and friends are a pretty crappy way of getting user input.

Comment: Updated my question, tested on Chrome and Firefox on Mac. @megawac - that doesn't work with "\x00Fred", what happens is I just get back "Fred" if you hit cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe I'm missing something** but for me, the `prompt()` function always returns `null` on cancel even if there is default answer.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TuzE3/3/

Answer (score 1):

Although using the prompt or alert functions are not the most optimum. here is how it's done

```
var defaultName = "Fred";
var name = prompt('What is your name?');

if (!name){
   // this section means they clicked cancel
   name = defaultName;
   // plus do anything else you want in case of cancel.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my test (Chrome and Safari for mac) cancel return empty string in this case, so try:

```
var name = prompt('What is your name?', 'Fred');
var hitCancel = !(name != "" && name !== null);
console.log(hitCancel)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GK5wq/